# Recursive tree in laravel with totals

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm thoroughly having an issue coming up with a solution to create a recursive hierarchy in mysql while summing the results as I go. Here's the quick structure to keep it simple.

```
----------------------
id | name | parent_id
----------------------
1  | A    | 0
2  | B    | 1
3  | C    | 1
4  | D    | 2
5  | E    | 2
6  | F    | 3
7  | G    | 3
```

I can recursively create this menu successfully as a php loop or in mysql:

```
A
-B
--D
--E
-C
--F
--G
```

However, I these IDs reference another table (contacts) and these are types of contacts. The issue is that only the leafs are assigned to the contacts, but I need to rollup the totals to each level. So I can get to:

```
A=0
-B=0
--D=100
--E=100
-C=0
--F=200
--G=200
```

But what I need is to roll up each subsection and sum that to the parent (without a lot of queries) In reality, this tree is several hundred elements in length. This is just a simplified version, but I can't figure out how to walk back up and end up with:

```
A=600
-B=200
--D=100
--E=100
-C=400
--F=200
--G=200
```

I'd be happy with a MySQL or PHP implementation. Really just anything to get me headed in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of elements in tree is small enough, you can use ranged IDs.

For example top most parent you can say id will be between 100000 - 199999, first child of this node can be between 100000-109999, second child between 110000-119999 etc. So you know for each node its children ids will be in certain range.

When you want count for a particular node, you just check if id is in that range. I hope this helps.